# How can i open a new route in a new page by clearing the previous homepage link. When i click submit the next page opens below the homepage

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

[image]

When i try to open a new route by clicking login button the new page named "hello" opens at the bottom of the login page instead of opening in a new page. How can i fix this?

Comment: Could you show the code of your router file?

Comment: please show your router file